# How to model an entity's current status in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am trying to get to grips with the ideas behind DDD and apply them to a pet project we have, and I am having some questions that I hope that someone here would be able to answer.

The project is a document management system. The particular problem we have regards two notions that our system handles: That of a `Document` and that of a `DocumentStatus`.

A `Document` has a number of properties (such as title, author, etc). Users can change any of the `Document`'s properties through out its life time.

A `Document` may be, at any time, be at a particular state such as `NEW`, `UNDER_REVISION`, `REVISED`, `APPROVED` etc. For each state we need to know who made that change to that state.

We need to be able to query the system based on a document status. An example query would be "Get me all documents that are in the `REVISED` state".

"Get me all documents whose status has been changed by user X"

The only time that a `Document` and a `DocumentStatus` need to be changed in the same transaction is when the `Document` is created (create the document and at the same time assign it a status of `NEW`).

For all other times, the UI allows the update of either but not both (i.e. you may change a document's property such as the author, but not its state.) Or you can update its state (from `NEW` to `UNDER_REVISION`) but not its properties.

I think we are safe to consider that a `Document` is an Entity and an Aggregate Root.

We are buffled about what `DocumentStatus` is. One option is to make it a Value Object part of the `Document`'s aggregate.

The other option is to make it an Entity and be the root of its own aggregate.

We would also liked to mention that we considered CQRS as described in various DDD documents, but we think it is too much of a hassle, especially given the fact that we need to perform queries on the `DocumentStatus`.

Any pointers or ideas would be welcomed.

Comment: Are you going to record all status transitions or only the current status?

Comment: We are going to record any status change. We record the new status, the person that requested it, the reason for change and a timestamp. So there would be more than one statuses for each document. The current status would be the last status entered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Domain

You say you need to be able to see past status changes, so the *status history* becomes a domain concept. A simple solution would then be the following:

- Define a `StatusHistory` within the `Document` entity.
- The `StatusHistory` is a list of `StatusUpdate` value objects.
- The first element in the `StatusHistory` always reflects the current state - make sure you add the initial state as `StatusUpdate` value object when creating `Document` entities.

Depending on how much additional logic you need for the status history, consider creating a dedicated value object (or even entity) for the history itself.

### Persistence

You don't really say how your persistence layer looks like, but I think creating queries against the first element of the `StatusHistory` list should be possible with every persistence mechanism. With a map-reduce data store, for example, create a view that is indexed by `Document.StatusHistory[0]` and use that view to realize the queries you need.

Comment: ok, but will the StatusHistory be on a separate Aggregate or the same Aggregate as the Document? I am asking because apart from the case of creation (where you have to create the document and the status history in the same transaction), in all other cases the two are updated separately. What other property do I need to look for to decide whether they are part of the same aggregate?

Comment: That depends on the invariants you have that affect `Document` and `StatusHistory`. If you need to enforce invariants between the two to remain consistent, they go in one aggregate. Only separate them if they can collaborate in an eventual-consistent manner.

Comment: @theDmi Hmm if I understand well they can be separated by introducing a DocumentStatusChanged domain event, which the StatusHistory can process and transform into a StatusUpdate value object/entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you were only to record the *current* status, then that could well be a value object.

Since you're composing more qualifying - if not identifying - data into it, for which you also intend to query, then that sounds to me as if no `DocumentStatus` is like another, so a value object doesn't make much sense, does it?

It is identified by

- the document
- the author
- the time it occurred

Furthermore, it makes even more sense in the context of the *previous* `DocumentStatus` (if you consider more states than just `NEW` and `UNDER_REVISION`).

To me, this clearly rules out modeling `DocumentStatus` as a value object.

In terms of the *state* as a property of `DocumentStatus`, and following the notion of *everything is an object* (currently reading David West's *Object Thinking*), then that could of course be modeled as a value object.

Follows [How to model an entity's current status in DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498474/how-to-model-an-entitys-current-status-in-ddd#comment56755221_34498474).